# Using find/sed to replace strings in text files- works only on some of the matches

Tags: regex, macos, sed

I want to replace

```
{not STRING }
```

with

```
(not STRING )
```

I ran

> find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sed -i -E 's/{not\s([^\s}]+)\s}/(not \1 )/g' {} ;

It worked on *some* of the matches. When I run `grep` with the same pattern it shows more files that still have `STRING`. Ran `find/sed` again, same result.

Comment: Please provide 1) Sample file including a line which is not replaced by find/sed but shown with grep 2) Your command line using grep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape curly braces (`{}`), as they are regex meta-characters. Also `\s` is not POSIX sed, I would use the more portable `[[:space:]]`.

Your code did not work on the example text for me (GNU/Linux). This does:

```
sed -E 's/\{not[[:space:]]+([^[:space:]}]+)[[:space:]]+\}/(not \1 )/g'
```

I also allowed for variable length whitespace directly after `not` and directly before `}` (using `[[:space:]]+`). You may or may not want that.

Also:

- On MacOS sed I believe you need to supply a suffix argument to `-i`.
- The trailing `;` for find `-exec` must be quoted (`\;`) to avoid interpretation by the shell.

So the command would be:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec \
sed -E -i .TMP 's/\{not[[:space:]]+([^[:space:]}]+)[[:space:]]+\}/(not \1 )/g' {} \;
```

If `.TMP` conflicts with an existing file, choose a different suffix.